# Send voice input to virtual NAOqi

Tags: nao-robot

I have a virtual robot running and I want to send a voice input to them with text, like the way that the dialog window in Choregraphe works. How can I do this using a Python script?

I am running the virtual robot from the terminal using the naoqi-bin application on Ubuntu with something like naoqi-bin -b 127.0.0.1 -p 9001

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [ALDialog.forceInput](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog-api.html#ALDialogProxy::forceInput__ssCR); something like this:

```
qiapp = qi.Application()
qiapp.start()
session = qiapp.session
session.service("ALDialog").forceInput("hey virtual nao how are you doing?")
```

Comment: Thanks. I found it after a while since it was buried in the API reference.